# What's the most reliable way to get a Flash file's run time in C#?

Tags: c#, flash

I've been trying to find a reliable way to get the length of time for video or animation contained in a flash (swf) file in a C# application. I've found a few references that show how to read out the header, but there are a couple problems with the header.

1. I've already run the code against several files in our company (produced by outside agencies) that have zero for their number of frames, which obviously isn't true when it is run in browser.
2. When files do actually have the information, the header isn't consistent between versions of flash. I can't even find a copy of the older headers that existed before Flash 7. Not having that, even for files that respect the header, I don't know which version before 7 was the last one with a different header format.

For reference, the application I am working on won't be trying to display the file, nor embed it. I'm only looking to catalog the running time of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash files don't work the way you think they do, so you won't be able to get their "run-time" by reading the SWF.

You can read the SWF to get the number of frames in the main timeline, but most Flash applications and movies will only have 2 frames on the main timeline.  One of these frames will then embed a MovieClip which itself can have any number of frames, or embed another MovieClip which also has a variable number of frames.  Yes, the child MovieClip can have more frames then the parent and Flash plays them back appropriately.

Besides that minor complication of embedded MovieClips, you also have ActionScript which can cause flash to jump around or replay frames which makes the number of frames in the source SWF completely irrelevant to the number of frames that actually play.  In fact most Flash applications really do only have two frames in the SWF but when played will have thousands or millions through the course of the runtime--it's just the same frame playing over and over again with ActionScript generating the content.

The only way to reliable get the runtime frame count is create a Flash application that loads another SWF, plays it, and counts frames.  If the loaded SWF is interactive then the number could vary from one run to the next.  That said, this is a process that can be automated, but you need to run the Flash Player either within an ActiveX container you can communicate with to get the results or have a service listening for posted data.

Comment: Actually, I did understand this. I understood the header doesn't have to contain the frames because most flash is used as conatainer for something else (video). That is why I was asking about a reliable way to get that information. So you'd say using the interop to talk to the IE flash plugin is probably the best way?

Comment: @Seneca, yup, that's one way.  You could also equally use the standalone flash player to run a container swf as long as there's a way for it to remote it's frame count when done (call out to a local web service).

Comment: The alternative sounds like what I considered with embedding it in a page, and using automation to have the page send ajax back to me, as it looks like javascript in page can interact with flash.

Comment: @Seneca, yes, JS can interact with Flash.  Look for `ExternalInterface`.